# pip install launch has problems

Tags: python, pip, module

I am trying to install the module 'launch' and it kept having dependency conflicts so I specified the version but it won't work cause of an error I do not know how to solve

```
$ pip install launch==0.1.3
    Collecting launch==0.1.3
      Using cached launch-0.1.3.tar.gz (10 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flowdas-meta<1.1,>=1.0.1 (from launch) (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for flowdas-meta<1.1,>=1.0.1
```

so far I tried installing different kinds of python versions and changing environment paths per change.. nothing has worked.. I also tried pip install flowdas, it did install flowdas but error still remains, pip install flowdas-meta does not work as well..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the launch dependencies: there is no flowdas-meta > 1; only a version 0.5.0 (actually, that is the flowdas package; there is no flowdas-meta on PyPI that I can find). You might file a bug report, but the homepage link from PyPI results in a dead end, so I think the launch package should be considered dead and abondoned. In other words, don't use it.

Comment: Note that comment in red near the top of [this page](https://libraries.io/pypi/flowdas-meta): "This package has been removed from Pypi and cannot be used anymore.".

Comment: I see, thanks for the answers, was doing this when I was manually installing, stable diffusion or was it webui for it, I already forgot, but I followed the instructions from git hub and got this error, I just went with the colab version now

Answer (score 2):

Even I was having many issues with `pip install launch` and getting the error:

```
"ERROR: Cannot install launch==0.1.0, launch==0.1.1, launch==0.1.2 and launch==0.1.3 
    because these package versions have conflicting dependencies. The conflict is caused by: 
    launch 0.1.3 depending on , 
    flowdas-meta\<1.1 and \>=1.0.1 
    launch 0.1.2 depends on 
    flowdas-meta\<1.1 and \>=1.0.1
    launch 0.1.1 depends on
    flowdas-meta\<1.1 and \>=1.0.1
    launch 0.1.0 depends on
    flowdas-meta\<1.1 and \>=1.0.1\
```

To fix this you can try to:

> 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
> 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to resolve the dependencies.

So I went ahead and downloaded them:

```
Downloading launch-0.1.3.tar.gz (10 kB)
Downloading launch-0.1.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
Downloading launch-0.1.1.tar.gz (10 kB)
Downloading launch-0.1.0.tar.gz (7.2 kB)
```

Upon examination of the `setup.py` in the folder `launch-0.1.3` the first line of `install_requires` had the call to download `flowdas` from a defunct https://bitbucket.org/flowdas/launch. It simply is nonexistent and there are a lot of people who couldn't download it, but still need it.

---

I went ahead and emailed the author. After all that I went and updated my [flowdas](https://pypi.org/project/flowdas/) to 0.5.0.

`pip install flowdas` installed it then I went back to `setup.py` and changed the first three lines to update to:

```
install_requires = [
        'flowdas>=0.5.0,<0.6.0',
        'click>=6.7,<6.8',
        'PyYAML>=3.12,<3.13'
```

to reflect all the new updated versions to be installed that includes all three lines. In the root folder of launch-0.1.3 I executed `pip install -e`, and wouldn't you know it installed, all of it.